# Good estimate for ratio $\frac{\gamma(d + s, x)}{\gamma(d,x)}$, where $\gamma$ is the lower incomplete gamma function.

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

Let $\gamma(d,x) := \int_{0}^xe^{-t}t^{d-1}dt$ (with $d,x > 0$) be the lower incomplete gamma function.

> **Question.** For $d,s,x > 0$ with $d \gg s$, what is a good estimate for the ratio
>   $$
> \frac{\gamma(d + s, x)}{\gamma(d,x)}.
> $$

I'm hoping some subtle application of Stirling's inequality is doable here.

Comment: For fixed $x>0$ and large positive $a$, we have $\gamma (a,x) \sim \frac{x^a e^{ - x}}{a}$. Thus for fixed positive $x$ and $s$, $\frac{\gamma (d + s,x)}{\gamma (d,x)} \sim x^s$ for large positive values of $d$.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't this bound be off when $x$ is also large (say $x \gg d \gg s$) ? In particular, how does your bound reconcile with the fact that $\frac{\gamma(d+s,x)}{\gamma(d,x)} \sim \frac{\Gamma(d+s)}{\Gamma(d)} \sim d^s$ for large $x$ ?

Comment: I would say that there is no very simple answer. If you denote $\lambda =x/d$, then using the uniform asymptotics of the incomplete gamma function, you get something like $\frac{\gamma (d + s,x)}{\gamma (d,x)} \sim d^s \frac{\mathrm{erfc}\left(  - \sqrt {d\left( \lambda  - 1 - \log \lambda  \right) - s\log \lambda }  \right)}{\mathrm{erfc}\left(  - \sqrt {d\left( \lambda  - 1 - \log \lambda  \right)} \right)}
$ for large $d$, uniformly in $\lambda>0$, and $s$ being fixed.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. Please don't hesitate package your comments and post them as an answer, so I can upvate / accept it.